# Should I create controller actions if they won't have their own page(view)?(what are best practices?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

I generated a controller:

rails generate controller Project title:string description:string plan:string

This creates the title, description & plan actions in my controller. However, I am now realizing that this may be overkill.

I want one project page that takes three input fields(title, description & plan). I don't want to have individual views for the three inputs but those are automatically created in my views folder. I could just leave those views blank but even as much as a newb as I am, I'm guessing this is not the way rails intends me to do this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: title,description and plan are the attributes not actions.

Comment: So when you generate the controller you pass actions not attributes? I should delete these actions, and create attributes in my Project Model. Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes!Those are not looked as a basic CRUD actions for a controller.Those are supposed to be attributes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who downvoted? It's an honest question. I saw myself in your position a few months ago. I think you should read the Rails Guides and play some [Rails4Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/levels/1)  first because you are confusing two parts of Rails, the model and the controller.

Controller actions are like things that you can do with your app. In this case of a project, you can most probably create, read/browse (either one Project or all projects), update, or delete projects. These are associated with views, which you'll learn at some point. Title, description, and plan_action are put into Models, which are usually saved in your database. Again, I recommend reading the guides and watching Zombies first so you get some information on how Rails works.

Comment: Would this work in my Project Model?                                class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :plan
  validates :title, :uniqueness => true
end

Comment: ActiveRecord automatically does the `attr_accessible` things for you. You need a corresponding database migration to create the things that your Project will latch onto. Ex: https://github.com/daryllxd/pageantus/blob/master/app/models/pageant.rb, I put validations but no `attr_accessible` and stuff

Comment: So I am doing Project < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :user validates :title, :uniqueness => true end     So then what will title, description & plan be, how will I use them? My best guess would be to create _partial(form)  and have them as instance variables within the form so I can use them in create & edit. Put the instance variable call in the edit & create actions in the controller?

Comment: Yep, something like that, check out other Rails apps to see how they do things

Comment: How/where do I check other rails apps? I can only view their HTML usually.   I think a better solution will be to have an @project variable for the whole form and just title, description & plan as inputs on the form rather then having them be instance variables now that I think of it.

Comment: Yes, you should instantiate an @project variable in your controller. Rails apps: http://www.opensourcerails.com/ (complex ones, but you might be fascinated by them). What I did was I looked for the Ruby user group in my area, in this case it was this: https://github.com/phrug. You have to find a Rails friend so you can exchange questions with each other :)